# createObjectURL(blob) saving static data despite overwriting document with new data

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript which reloads a Chrome page and saves the html via a createObjectURL(blob) which I need to run on a loop from a bookmarklet.

All appears well at first glance, the page is refershing with new data viaible in the chrome window and the save via blob is working to give me the page data in a consumable format.

HOWEVER... The data is refreshing in the Chrome window but the saved html is not, it is the same data saved continuously. I cannot for the life of me see why! :(

The blob is being recreated everytime the 'download' funtion is called so should contain the new data from the 'document' which is being written over by the 'reload' function, no?

Please help, this is driving me crazy!

```
javascript: 
timeout=10; 
current=location.href; 
if(timeout>0) 
  setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout); 
else 
  location.replace(current); 
  setInterval(download,1250*timeout,document.documentElement.innerHTML,"test.html"); 
function download(text, filename){
  var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/html"});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();
}
function reload(){ 
  setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout); 
  fr4me='<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame src=\''+current+'\'/>'; 
  fr4me+='</frameset>'; 
  with(document){write(fr4me);void(close())}; 
}
```

Comment: try this
`setInterval(
  function (){
    download(document.documentElement.innerHTML,"test.html")
  },
  1250*timeout
);`

Comment: @JuanCaicedo Thanks but I'm afraid this is not a solution for me. Im fact the results are worse as the html file produced using this contains only a reference to the src page -        <head></head><frameset cols="*">
                            <frame src="https\\www.example.com"></frameset>                        - rather than the full html which I get (once) from the other method.